# Is there a free, local-only "AI box"?

Tags: windows, gratis, artificial-intelligence

I keep hearing every single day about "AI". "AI" is claimed to revolutionize the world. But yet I see none of this AI.

I've seen countless weird websites which contain "AI" but actually offer no actual product for me to download and run. I'm not looking to sign up for some "waiting list" or to pay money for "API access".

I'm looking for an `AI.exe` which I download and then I can query it various things and it will answer me intelligently. For example:

```
AI.exe "How much is two apples + 42 apples?"
```

And it would return JSON output with a string such as:

```
44
```

I don't want it to make any external requests, so it would have a bunch of useful databases baked into it. I expect it to understand math, units and stuff like that. I naturally don't expect to be able to query it about "anything".

Even if this would have limited use, it would be very cool to be able to have my own offline, privacy-respecting "AI" where I can ask various questions instead of having to feed them into search engines and let the world know exactly what I'm thinking about or doing at the moment.

My guess is that even this just doesn't exist. AI seems to be vaporware/fluff.

Comment: Why isn't the answer "44 apples" or "The answer is 44 apples" or "2 apples + 42 apples is 44 apples" or "Adding two apples and 42 apples gives 44 apples" or ...? Why should the output be JSON?

Comment: Other than that, AI is not fluff, nor doesn't it exist. But it's just mathematics, i.e. statistics. For the task described by you, one needed a 2800 core processor and 16 TB of RAM. It was not ready for personal use in 2011 and its name is [Watson](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Watson_(computer))

Comment: Wolfram alpha happily [solves the task](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=How+much+is+two+apples+%2B+42+apples%3F) and [you can buy it](https://products.wolframalpha.com/appliance/). Maybe it's not gratis because the development cost milllions.

Comment: Why the answer should be json? Maybe it could say on Oxford English that fourty-four. :-)

Comment: Welcome Hyram!  The example you provide, although it is what comes into many people's minds initially, represents a narrow and specific definition of AI.  The concepts of AI extend far beyond the example.  That said, much of what is called "AI" today is really not what we called "AI" many years ago.  In addition to having real meaning, "AI" is also currently an en vogue marketing term that is often used to boost sales and corporate valuations.  Part of the challenge is defining intelligence, and to a further degree, consciousness.

Answer (score 1):

If you are a data scientist, iris looks interesting: https://github.com/Ejhfast/iris-agent

It is a domain specific conversational agent used to perform common tasks and calculations in the field of data science.

Also, if you're a programmer, do some research and start buidling your own neural networks. There are some good tensorflow tutorials out there, for example, just do a web search. There is a large difference between a hello world example and a cutting edge application such as autonomous vehicles, but the more you learn the less AI (however you define that) seems like magic or fluff and the more it seems like math. Really hard math.

Answer (score -1):

I hear that you can use language-model [GPT-3](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GPT-3), interactively, via AI-Dungeon, yourself. You have to setup a paid account, but it's $10/month and has (had?) a 7 day free trial.

(It's not local-only, needs Internet Access)

It's not great, but .. in any case, you'll be convinced its almost certainly not a hoax when it generates human-like responses  for you in real time.

(from Hacker News)